# How to round and add new columns in a Data Table?

Tags: r

I am new to R. Please help me with the below problem.

My data.table looks like this - 
[image]

I want to do some calculations on sic and naics columns only. I need to add four more new columns into data.table namely TwoDigitSic, ThreeDigitSic, TwoDigitNaics and ThreeDigitNaics.
For making it TwoDigit, divide three digit values by 10 and four digit by 100 and so on.
also I do not want to use round(x). It should be floor(x).

Sample Code of the Data.table:-
    library(readxl)
    library(data.table)
    library(xlsx)
    library(openxlsx)

```
uk = read.csv("C:\\Users\\talgotra\\Desktop\\CE Count\\latest\\rawDD_monthly_UK40.csv")

data = as.data.table(uk)
```

The output should be like -

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and not as images. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
data$TwoDigitSic <- as.numeric(substr(Sic, 1, 2))
data$ThreeDigitSic <- as.numeric(substr(Sic, 1, 3))
data$TwoDigitNaics <- as.numeric(substr(Naics, 1, 2))
data$ThreeDigitNaics <- as.numeric(substr(Naics, 1, 3))
```

Comment: I want to convert SIC and NAICS into two digit and three digit. for 1287 = 12 and 128 < like this

Comment: It works as required, Example > Sic<- c(12545, 138, 13564, 568) #
> as.numeric(substr(Sic, 1, 2)) #
[1] 12 13 13 56 # Unless you supply reproducible sample, we couldn't check it.